# Autostart Chromium in Lubuntu 12.04

Tags: lubuntu

I'm new Lubuntu and I want to start Chromium at boot. I've no idea where to start. Could someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

- Press Window key and search for **Startup Applications**
- Click on Add Button
- Name: Chromium
- Command: /usr/bin/chromium-browser

PS: I use Ubuntu and not Lubuntu but I think it should do the job.

Comment: The procedure is very different, I believe, for Unity and LXDE.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the answer to your question will also help me solve mine... I am a linux newbie too.

I discovered Lubuntu does not have a "Start up Applications" in the menu. From googling I found that to auto start apps, you have to:

```
gksudo leafpad /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

I think you can just add a line to this:

```
@chromium
```

That is an educated guess. If that doesn't work, try the full path to the executable. Something like:

```
@/usr/bin/chromium-browser/chromium
```

Please let me know if that works. I am learning too!